# Mathematical Research Vs Project (undergraduate)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, thermodynamics, particle-physics

This question may not be appropriate for this site, and if so should be closed by a moderator. I'll ask it anyways though.

Im currently a junior in my undergraduate degree (math & physics). I am looking to go to graduate school for mathematical physics. I was talking to a professor about how I would go about doing research in mathematical physics since it is so inaccessible to undergraduates. He recommended not worrying about finding REUs but instead to do some projects that professors in the math/physics department are willing to help guid me in.

The only problem is: whats the difference between a project and a research question? How would I go about finding a project that I could actually pursue? Do any of you have experience doing a Sr. Research topic in mathematical physics? How did you go about it.

Im primarily interested in analytical problems, and as far as math goes i'm really open. I like Complex analysis, Functional Analysis, PDE's, Deterministic Models, etc (i'm not super experienced in all these fields but I figured if I start early that wont be a problem, I can fill in the gaps as I go so to speak).

*[The professor mentioned some problem related to perturbation theory but I cant for the life of me remember what it was specifically.]*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about physics.

Comment: @Emilio Pisanty Im asking about project topics in mathematical physics though? I worried mostly that it is too opinion based for this site.

Comment: We generally take educational and career advice questions to be off topic for this site.

Comment: @DavidZ is there a better thread for this question or is it better served for places like r/AskPhysics on reddit?

Comment: You could try [chat], if you have access there (it requires 20-ish total reputation across the entire SE network). Otherwise, yeah, reddit might be the place for this.

Comment: I gave you a +1 so that the reputation rises and you can go to chat